# iOS Mail uses wrong return address

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

tl;dr: I have several email addresses on the same Mail account, iOS defaults to the wrong one as the sender, and I can't figure out how to change that.

Full version:

I set up my email accounts on my Mac. In Mac OS X Mail's Accounts prefs, it's possible to list several email addresses for an account in a comma-delimited list. I do this, and it works well on the Mac. In the Composing prefs in Mail, I set **Send new messages from** to my primary email address, and that's the one that gets used by default.

On iOS, Mail uses a different email address in the **From** and **Reply-To** headers. (It's an address I only use for email to/from Yahoo groups). I haven't been able to find anything like Mac OS X Mail's **Send new messages from** setting, so I don't know how I can change this. As a result, email from iOS defaults to having a return address that I really don't want it to have. I only get the preferred address if I remember to change it, every single time.

Deleting the address isn't an option-- I do actually use it, sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS Mail app doesn't function like you are hoping it will unfortunately. The best suggestion I have is to add this mail account twice in iOS Settings, once using each email address you prefer it to have.

Comment: Sigh, that's what I thought. Bug filed with Apple...